# Programmatically bypass "touch to configure" Android Widget

Tags: java, android, xml, initialization, config

I would like to know how to bypass the "Touch to Configure" on my android widget programmatically. Once I have installed the android widget on my device it says "Touch to configure" which then executes my class **"IntelligenWidgetConfig.java"**. But I want this to automatically happen on start up of my application. Can anyone advise me on how to approach this method or any solution that might help?

**Android Config Class:**

```
public class IntelliGenWidgetConfig extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "IntelliGenWidgetConfig";

    public IntelliGenWidgetConfig() {
        super();
    }

    public static int getAppWidgetId(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("Intelligen", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return settings.getInt("appWidgetId", 1);
    }

    protected void setAppWidgetId(int id) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Intelligen", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("appWidgetId", id);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if they press the back button.
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            setAppWidgetId(extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID));
        }

        // If they gave us an intent without the widget id, just bail.
        if (getAppWidgetId(this) == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
        }

        final Context context = IntelliGenWidgetConfig.this;

        RegisterForPushNotification(context);

        // Push widget update
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.intelligen_widget_layout);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(getAppWidgetId(this), views);

        // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, getAppWidgetId(this));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }

    private void RegisterForPushNotification(Context ctx) {
        Intent registerIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        registerIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        registerIntent.putExtra("sender", "209845001369");
        startService(registerIntent);
    }

    private void DeregisterFromPushNotification(Context ctx) {
        Intent unregisterIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
        unregisterIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        startService(unregisterIntent);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml (section):**

```
   <activity android:name=".IntelliGenWidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:minHeight="360dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/intelligen_widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="vertical"
    android:minResizeWidth="280dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="70dp"
    android:configure="za.co.infotech.www.intelligen.IntelliGenWidgetConfig"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview">
</appwidget-provider>
```